# Why is my Android phone always showing "contacts storage space is low"?

Tags: contacts, insufficient-memory

My Android phone is always showing "contacts storage space is low". Even if I delete all of my contacts in the phone, I still get this message, and I can't store any new contact now.

What is more, my SIM card shows that it is 95% full, but when I select "multi-delete"->SIM, I found no contacts at all.

What should I do?